# Prevent More than 1 cell From Being Changed While Ignoring if the Cells' Contents Were Deleted

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create an Excel VBA macro that will detect if more than one cell is being changed at a time. I also want it to ignore the code if a person is only deleting the cells.

This works for checking if more than one cell is being changed and will prevent the change:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then
        MsgBox "Change only one cell at a time", , "Too Many Changes!"
        Application.Undo
    End If

    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

I am trying to figure out how to get it so it ignores it when the contents of the cells are being deleted. I have tried many combinations of stuff using `KeyAscii`, `Chr`, `ClearContents`, and several other things. I can't seem to get it to work. Below is the last thing I tried.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then
        If KeyAscii <> vbKeyDelete Then
            MsgBox "Change only one cell at a time", , "Too Many Changes!"
            Application.Undo
        End If
    End If

    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Please let me know if someone has any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim cl As Variant
    Dim dat As Variant
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then
        dat = Target.Formula

        For Each cl In dat
            If cl <> "" Then
                MsgBox "Change only one cell at a time", , "Too Many Changes!"
                Application.Undo
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    End If

    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Explanation:

`dat = Target.Formula` copies the Formula's from a range into a 2D variant array.
The `.Formula` is to avoid treating formulas that happen to return an empty string as blanks
`For Each cl in dat` iterates each element of the array
If `cl` is non blank then the user cannot have deleted the range, so trigger then message and undo

I could have used `For Each Cl in Target` (where `cl` is Dim'ed as `Range`), but copying to a variant array is faster that looping over a range.

Comment: Thank you so much for posting this, this is great, it does work. Can you please explain what the .Formula is? Is that just representing the contents (the text) within multiple changed cells, else is it representing the number of selected cells or their range, or all of this (contents, number of cells, and range)? Once I understand the .Formula I will then understand what the dat variant is.

Comment: What is the cl variant, since it isn’t defined anywhere other than being a variant. Like I understand what dat is since it equals something (that is I will understand what it is once I understand what .Formula is), but cl doesn’t equal anything. I think cl = “” since it isn’t defined, so it is empty. If that is correct then what I think is happening when I delete something is each empty cell, which is the cl variant, is searching in the dat variant for any cells that aren’t empty. Like if 3 cells were deleted then it will loop three times searching for a cell that is not empty.

Comment: If you don’t mind, can you please explain this to me? I am grateful for the code and it will be very helpful, but I would really like to understand how the code works that I am using. Usually I am able to create my own code, but this one did stump me and I don’t fully understand it.

Thanks again for your help,

Chris

Comment: A range's `Formula` property is an array containing all the formulas of the range. For cells that contain constants, their `Formula` is equal to their `Value`.  `Cl` is populated by the `For` loop, one value from `dat` each time through the loop.  To help understand this, put a breakpoint on the code, and examine the variables in a watch window while single stepping through the code.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I appreciate it. I did step through the code before and was still somewhat confused, but you clarified it for me. Thanks again.